# How does the zsh list-colors syntax work?

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I am trying to set the list-colors for a completion function, but I just can't wrap my head around the styling syntax.

```
zstyle ':completion:*:tasks:*' list-colors "=(#b) #([^ ]#)*=$color[white]=$color[yellow]=$color[red]"
```

All i know is that '#' and '##' are the regex equivalents of '.' and '+'. Every time I try to modify the syntax just a little, the matching seems to break. Could somebody please post some easy examples or resources (unfortunately the zsh docs have very few examples)? How would I, for instance match the string '--'?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here come a few examples.

Something simple for beginning, let all parameters tag be in green:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:parameters'  list-colors '=*=32'
```

As you can see syntax is '=pattern=format'.
Since * matches everything and 32 is ANSI green code, thus all parameters will be green.

Now lets show all commands in bolded red

```
zstyle ':completion:*:commands' list-colors '=*=1;31'
```

but built-in commands with a little bit more sophisticated color (from 256 palette)

```
zstyle ':completion:*:builtins' list-colors '=*=1;38;5;142'
```

analogously for aliases

```
zstyle ':completion:*:aliases' list-colors '=*=2;38;5;128'
```

Now lets go to patterns, and colorize different parts of completion differently, say we want a kill processes in 3 different colors:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:kill:*' list-colors '=(#b) #([0-9]#)*( *[a-z])*=34=31=33'
```

Here syntax is a little bit more complicated, namely
'=(#b)(pattern1)(pattern2)=format0=format1=format2'
where format0 is used for everything which do not match any patterns.
So processes IDs (first pattern) will be in red, processes names (second pattern) in yellow, and the rest in blue:

[image]

Lastly lets try something useful with '--' string which you asked for:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:options' list-colors '=^(-- *)=34'
```

This will present all command options in blue, but description of that options will stay normal.

[image]

Notice that some options starts with '--', so we have to use '-- ' (with space) to match only descriptions, and negate pattern with ^ to apply color for options.

Hope this help

Comment: I'm having issues with the last example for colouring the descriptions ... https://superuser.com/questions/1200487/zsh-completion-list-colors-partial-colouring-issue

Comment: What is the `#b`? Having trouble finding relevant documentation.

Comment: (#b) not #b is a flag that enables matching of parenthesized expressions. Its documented in: "22.7.1 Colored completion listings" of zsh manual.